# Raise Improperly configured psycopg2(postgresql)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7

I am new to django. I had tried to configure postgresql with my project.
steps what i followed:

1) sudo apt-get install psycopg2

2) changing settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

3) running python manage.py makemigrations

but i am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/vivekpradhan/joker/basket/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: You need to install `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2`.

Comment: its showing python-psycopg2 is already there in newest form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try installing it in your virtualenv using the below command:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

To globally install, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

Answer (score 6):

When I encountered this problem although the package was already installed it helped to reinstall it. Not sure why.

```
(venv) $ pip uninstall psycopg2
(venv) $ pip install psycopg2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
python -m pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev python-psycopg2
```